# Yii2: Adding php sprintf function to format value in gridview

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to add leading zeros to a number to be shown in gridview.
I am trying this code, but it is throwing error like:

> Getting unknown property: app\models\OpdTestBill::0000

The code I am using is like this:

```
[
'attribute'=>'dhanwantri_bill_number',
'format'=>'raw',
'value'=>sprintf('%04d','dhanwantri_bill_number')
],
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve this?

Thanks.

**Variation**

```
[ 'attribute'=>'dhanwantri_bill_number',
   'format'=>sprintf('%04d','dhanwantri_bill_number')
  ],
```

Here too I am getting the error:

> Unknown format type: 0000
>   throw new InvalidParamException("Unknown format type: $format")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution, anyone having problem can find it useful:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'dhanwantri_bill_number',
    'value'     => function($model) {
        return sprintf('%04d', $model->dhanwantri_bill_number);
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation of `sptrinf` [here](http://php.net/sprintf).

The first parameter is the format that is being used for the output, which you chose to be an integer with leading zeros in case the value is `< 1000`.
The following parameters have to match the format.

> `sprintf('%04d','dhanwantri_bill_number')`

You set an integer as output but gave a string as input. `sprintf` doesn't know to do with that, since it was looking for an integer.

```
sprintf('%04d',12);
// Output:
0012
```

Comment: Thanks moonlight - I have updated the question with the variation you suggested. I understand the php  `sprintf` function, only the correct syntax for using it in `Yii framework` is causing the headache. I am giving the field attribute, how I can replace that can please suggest that.